# Firestore transaction - Transaction failed: TypeError: transaction.set(...).then is not a function

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I have written a transaction to check if a user exists in Firestore before attempting to create it.

```
  setUserData(uid, email, displayName, photoURL, firstName, lastName, referralId) {
    const userRef = this.afs.firestore.collection('users').doc(`${uid}`);
    return this.afs.firestore.runTransaction(async (transaction: any) => {
      const doc = await transaction.get(userRef);
      let userData = {};
      if (!doc.exists) {
        userData = {
          uid: uid,
          email: email,
          displayName: displayName,
          photoURL: photoURL,
          emailVerified: true,
          firstName: firstName,
          lastName: lastName,
          referralId: referralId
        };
        transaction.set(userRef, { userData }, { merge: true }).then(() => {
          this.referralService.addUserToWaitlist(referralId);
        });
      }
    }).then(() => {
      if (!environment.production) {
        console.log(
          'Transaction successfully committed.'
        );
      }
    }).catch((error) => {
      if (!environment.production) {
        console.log('Transaction failed: ', error);
      }
    });
  }
```

However, I keep getting the following error:

```
Transaction failed:  TypeError: transaction.set(...).then is not a function
```

Does `transaction` not have the equivalent of `then`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how writing documents works in a transaction.  Since a transaction is an all-or-nothing operation, you can't wait for a `set()` to complete before moving on to another one, so it wouldn't be helpful for it to return a promise.  With transactions, you have to `set()` all your documents before the end of your function, then at the end, the transaction will attempt to write them all.  If they cannot all be written atomically, your transaction function will be run again.

Also notice that the plain JavaScript API (not Angular) for [transaction.set()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Transaction#set) is declared to return the same Transaction object rather than a promise.

Comment: Hi Doug, is the following ok: https://pastebin.com/3ZiQKXFP? I've removed `then()` from the query. Now I get the following error: `Transaction failed:  Error: Every document read in a transaction must also be written.`

Comment: That means you're reading a document in the transaction but not also setting it, which is not legal.

Comment: But I set it here: `transaction.set(userRef, { userData }, { merge: true });`

Comment: I don't know, sounds like a completely different problem than the one you first posted about.  Please try asking a new question to separate your concerns.